# Column family ID mismatch Error on a single node cluster

Tags: cassandra-2.0

My keyspace is created as:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE <some_keyspace> WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

However I am running a single node cluster:

```
./nodetool status <some_keyspace>
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
XX  XXX.XXX.XXX.XX  3.73 GB    256     100.0%            <uid>  rack1
```

And things were still running fine till today, when we encountered:

```
ERROR [MigrationStage:1] 2015-08-13 01:58:49,249 CassandraDaemon.java:153 - Exception in thread Thread[MigrationStage:1,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found <uid>; expected <uid>)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.reload(CFMetaData.java:1125) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTables.updateColumnFamily(DefsTables.java:422) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTables.mergeColumnFamilies(DefsTables.java:295) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTables.mergeSchemaInternal(DefsTables.java:194) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTables.mergeSchema(DefsTables.java:166) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager$2.runMayThrow(MigrationManager.java:393) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found <uid>; expected <uid>)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.validateCompatility(CFMetaData.java:1208) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.apply(CFMetaData.java:1140) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.reload(CFMetaData.java:1121) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Did notetool repair, probably didn't work so after few mins did a restart and then the problem went away.

Need help in understanding what caused it and how it was resolved.

Will using `IF NOT EXISTS` clause in create table help? I doubt.

Comment: I am facing same problem even after using `IF NOT EXISTS`. I did not try running nodetool repair because when accessing through `cqlsh` there is no problem.